# Login control with member ship

Tags: asp.net, authentication

i have created a small website for using **login control**

and i have done every thing

but on executing  i m getting 
error message

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed " Location:
>   "http://localhost/WebSite/Login.aspx" Line Number 1, Column 2:<%@ Page
>   Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs"
>   Inherits="Login" %> "
>   -^

Answer (score 0):

Sanjay you can delete space between Page and @

```
<%@Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>
```